# Read a data.txt file and calculate mean etc in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **`date.txt`** file:

```
Time    suit    helmet  golves  boots
1   5   6   5   8
3   1   2   7   8
5   2   4   6   5
6   6   3   8   4
```

I want to calculate mean, std etc. for each column. How do I do that?

```py
rootPathin = r"C:\Python"
rootPathout=r"C:\Python"

case = "data.txt"

input_filename  = os.path.join(rootPathin, case)
output_filename = os.path.join(rootPathout, "mean.txt")

time_values = []
# Open the input file in read mode
with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_file:
# Open the output file in write mode
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
# Read the contents of the input file line by line
        df = [input_filename]
        
        mean = df['suit'].mean()
        
        std = df['suit'].std()
        
        print("suit mean = ",mean, "and suit STD = ", std)
```

I am getting error:

```
C:\Python>py readfileout.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\readfileout.py", line 25, in <module>
    mean = df['suit'].mean()
           ~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: According the error, `df` is of type list. You probably want to create a dataframe: `df = pd.read_csv(input_filename)`

Comment: You can't create a dataframe directly from a filename. You need to call a function like `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: You're opening the input file, but you never read anything from it.

Comment: The data.txt file is: column labels and data underneath with spaces, not a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use Pandas, then `df.describe()` function. Assuming the file is **data.txt** and used single spaces as separators (change both as you require) then:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep = ' ')
print(df.describe())
```

gives summary of stats information:

```
           Time      suit    helmet    golves     boots
count  4.000000  4.000000  4.000000  4.000000  4.000000
mean   3.750000  3.500000  3.750000  6.500000  6.250000
std    2.217356  2.380476  1.707825  1.290994  2.061553
min    1.000000  1.000000  2.000000  5.000000  4.000000
25%    2.500000  1.750000  2.750000  5.750000  4.750000
50%    4.000000  3.500000  3.500000  6.500000  6.500000
75%    5.250000  5.250000  4.500000  7.250000  8.000000
max    6.000000  6.000000  6.000000  8.000000  8.000000
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use tabulation `\t` as separator :

```py
import os
import pandas as pd


rootPathin = r"C:\Python"
rootPathout=r"C:\Python"
case = "data.txt"

input_filename = os.path.join(rootPathin, case)
output_filename = os.path.join(rootPathout, "mean.txt")

df = pd.read_csv(input_filename, sep='\t')

# Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the 'suit' column
mean = df['suit'].mean()
std = df['suit'].std()

print("suit mean =", mean, "and suit STD =", std)

# Write the mean value to the output file
with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write("suit mean = " + str(mean) + " and suit STD = " + str(std))
```

Prints in mean.txt file :

```
suit mean = 3.5 and suit STD = 2.3804761428476167
```